# Mobile cross-platform client side encryption

Tags: windows-7, ios, encryption

I know there are several pieces of software which offer the ability to encrypt files client-side and other software which encrypts files server-side, but that's not what I want.  I'm planning to begin using the cloud to sync files between my iDevices and Windows PC.  I'm currently using iTunes, but this doesn't provides a true 'sync' feature (i.e. it doesn't update files automatically).  My concern with using the cloud is that I want my files to be encrypted, but on the client side.  So basically what I'm looking for is encryption software which will run on a Windows PC and iOS to allow decryption of files from the cloud (specifically OneDrive).  As I don't want it to go through a third party to encrypt I expect the encryption key would sync via iTunes (just a suggestion).

Summary:

- Allows encryption of files before uploading to the cloud (OneDrive)
- Is cross-platform (specifically between Windows PC and iOS)
- Does **NOT** sync the encryption key through a third party (i.e. client-side encryption key created)
- Is free software (I wish is to be free on Windows, but I don't mind paying a modest fee for the app for iOS i.e. between free (ideal) up to $4.99)

I have seen [Prot-On](https://www.prot-on.com/tryIt.html), but I am unsure whether this is actually what I am looking for (anyone with personal experience may be able to help here, as the website doesn't make it clear to me).

Thanks in advance